# How do I iterate through nested TreeMaps?

Tags: java, iteration, treemap

I have a set of 3 nested TreeMaps:

```
TreeMap<DayOfWeek, TreeMap<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>>> keyDay = new TreeMap<DayOfWeek, TreeMap<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>>>();
TreeMap<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>> keyCourt = new TreeMap<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>>();
TreeMap<Time, String> keyTime = new TreeMap<Time, String>();
```

which store info for bookings. I'm trying to iterate through them using nested while loops to show all the bookings that have been created, but I need a way in the nested whiles to show only the values which relate to the relevant parent.

Here's what I have:

```
        Iterator listOfDays = keyDay.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator listOfCourts = keyCourt.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator listOfTimes = keyTime.keySet().iterator();
    String output;

    while (listOfDays.hasNext()) {
        DayOfWeek currentDay = (DayOfWeek) (listOfDays.next());
        output += currentDay.toString() + "\n----------\n";
        while (listOfCourts.hasNext()){
            Court currentCourt = (Court) (listOfCourts.next());
            output += currentCourt.toString() + ":\n";
            while (listOfTimes.hasNext()){
                Time currentTime = (Time) (listOfTimes.next());
                String currentName = (String) keyTime.get(currentTime);
                output += currentTime.toString() + " - " + currentName + "\n";
            }
        }
```

...but as expected (but not wanted), it just iterates through all the entries in each TreeMap til the end.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is confusing here is that you speak of nested trees, and indeed keyDay is nested, but then you do not touch the nested trees, instead, you go over unrelated trees.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you mean, but let me give you an example of how I'm trying to structure the 'records' in my trees: [day, [court#,[time,name]]].

Comment: Use typed collections, if you can. You'll save lots of keystrokes and improve type-safety of your code.

Comment: have a look at EnumSet and EnumMap. your data lends itself to be enum'd and this can improve type safety as Victor points out.

Comment: Alas I need to do this with TreeMaps - a set assignment!

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear (what are listOfDays, listOfCourts and listOfTimes?), but I guess you need something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<DayOfWeek, TreeMap<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>>> dayEntry : keyDay.entrySet()) {
    DayOfWeek currentDay = dayEntry.getKey();
    output += currentDay.toString() + "\n----------\n";
    for (Map.Entry<Court, TreeMap<Time, String>> courtEntry : dayEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        Court currentCourt = courtEntry.getKey();
        output += currentCourt.toString() + ":\n";
        for (Map.Entry<Time, String> timeEntry : currentCourt.getValue().entrySet()) {
            Time currentTime = timeEntry.getKey();
            String currentName = timeEntry.getValue();
            output += currentTime.toString() + " - " + currentName + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

In short, a map can be viewed as a set of map entries, and you can iterate through this entry set. Each entry has a key and a value. Since the value, in your case, is another map, you can repeat this operation on the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. listOfDays, listOfCourts and listOfTimes are just iterator variables for the keys in each of the TreeMaps - (Mon,Tues,Wed etc), (Court 1, Court 2, Court 3 etc) and (0900,0945,1030 etc). The problem is that I can't seem to iterate only those values relating to a single key in the parent TreeMap. I tried your code but got errors about needing an instance of java.lang.Iterable - do TreeMaps not count?

Comment: @melatOnin: A Map itself is not Iterable, but it has three methods `values()` (a collection of the map's values), `keySet` (a collection of the keys) and `entrySet()` (a collection of the entries, i.e. key-value-pairs). In the code in this answer, `.entrySet()` should be added in each of the loops.

Comment: I edited my answer. @melat0nin : You could have spotted the error and found the solution yourself by looking at the documentation for TreeMap: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/.